# Oracle Outer Join cause ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have Oracle 11.2.0 (x64) installed on my personal development environment.  When running SQL selections that Left Join more than 10 tables I am easily to get Oracle crash with ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file.  If I use Inner Join there is no such problem.  For a same particular query this happens all the time, no matter how many data is in my database (in fact not much data is there, no more than several hundred rows.)

I work with around 100 people who install Oracle with same version and roughly same settings, and apparently not seen anywhere else as far as I know.

This error can be triggered no matter if I run the query from SQL Developer or using C#.Net Data Access.

Any ideas please?

My Alert/Log.Xml has these:

Exception [type: ACCESS_VIOLATION, UNABLE_TO_READ] [ADDR:0x45] [PC:0x35797B4, _kkqstcrf()+1342]

and
Errors in file c:\oracle\diag\rdbms\orcl1\orcl1\trace\orcl1_ora_1192.trc  (incident=41028):
ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [kkqstcrf()+1342] [ACCESS_VIOLATION] [ADDR:0x45] [PC:0x35797B4] [UNABLE_TO_READ] []

Comment: Check this note 1069517.1

Comment: @g00dy, thank you for your reply.  I installed oracle on windows 7.  I checked the services and made sure the oracle service and listener service are logged on as same account (Local System).  Also the ORA-12537 only happens to me when I have more than 10 outer join tables in the selection.  If it's note 1069517.1, I suppose it should happen all the time?

Comment: You should really provide some example code that you're running. I can't tell at this point ... it might be 10 different things. If i were you, I would confirm your hypothesis of "joining more than 10 tables". Say, you join 20 tables - are you sure you get this every singe time, no matter the table combination? I mean, try removing some joins from the query, start from the small tables and add more until you get the error. Then swap some tables in that join and see if it reproduces with more of less tables again. And code here please :)

Comment: Also, paste here the value of the parameters `optimizer_search_limit` and `optimizer_max_permutations`.

Comment: Check the Alert log as well. There might be something else on top of this error, that actually causes it.

Comment: Thank you @g00dy !  The query is really very simple.  Like select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id left join table3 on table3.id = table2.table3_id ....  I pasted alert log up there but still not too much information.  If I left join like that for 10 tables (some can be left join for multiple times for different fields) it will give me result.  If I left join one more table, it will break.  I can replace tables (like a complicated table with smaller simple tables) but does not seem to change result.  The 2 parameters you mentioned are both not specified

Comment: Try using the "Oracle" left-join syntax. At least try it, I can't tell if it's going to help. I merely have seen quite many cases where getting back to the old, non-ANSI syntax helped. Alas, Oracle still has bugs in their internal transformations of ANSI-joins.

Comment: Ok, so .. the parameter `optimizer_max_permutations`(1p for short) has a default value of 180 000, which is the max permutations of possible table join combinations. The parameter `optimizer_search_limit` (2p for short) has a default of 5, which gives you !5 = 120 possible permutations. In order to check this, set 2p to the number of tables joined, say 9, which should yield more than 320 000 permutations and should evaluate the query. Check this link, it explains it really well http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_builder_opt_limit.htm